# How do you read or assign a value to a single cell in a tibble, using the name of the column?

Tags: r, variable-assignment, tibble

I'm learning the `tidyverse` and ran into a problem with the simplest of operations:reading and assigning value to a single cell.  I need to do this by matching a specific value in another column and calling the name of the column whose value I'd like to change (so I can't use numeric row and column numbers).

I've searched online and on SO and read the tibble documentation (this seems the most applicable https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html?q=cell) and haven't found the answer.  (I'm probably missing something - apologies for the simplicity of this question and if it's been answered elsewhere)

`test<-tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1, z = x ^ 2 + y)`

Yields:

```
 A tibble: 5 x 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2
2     2     1     5
3     3     1    10
4     4     1    17
5     5     1    26
```

`test["x"==3,"z"]`

Yields:

```
 A tibble: 0 x 1
 … with 1 variable: z <dbl>
```

But doesn't tell me the value of that cell.

And when I try to assign a value...

`test["x"==3,"z"]<-20`

...it does not work.

`test[3,3]`  This works, but as stated above I need to call the cell by names not numbers.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a data.table.  If we are using `base R` methods, the columns 'x' is extracted with `test$x` or `test[["x"]]`

```
test[test$x == 3, "z"]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#     z
#  <dbl>
#1    10
```

Or use `subset`

```
subset(test, x == 3, select = 'z')
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
       filter(x == 3) %>%
       select(z)
```

Or if we want to pass a string as column name, convert to `sym`bol and evaluate

```
test %>% 
    filter(!!  rlang::sym("x") == 3) %>% 
    select(z)
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(test)[x == 3, .(z)]
#    z
#1: 10
```

Comment: Ah, duh...  I forgot about that first method of identifying rows. - Thanks.  
Now we've just got to find the old question to mark this as a duplicate of.